# Debugging Firebase with Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to debug why I can't get messages from firebase on my iPhone, 
I am connected to the FCM server, and I've also subscribed to a topic, however, when I try to print data recieved from FCM I get nil values.

This is the code I have from google's tutorial, it gets executed so that does mean the app is being notified correctly that a new topic is available on FCM?

Also how can I debug to see if there's something I'm doing wrong in setting FCM up?

Thanks

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.

     FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/newNotificationtest")
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"])")


    debugPrint(userInfo)
    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the sample for [Firebase Messaging for Swift](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging)?

Comment: When I created a new app and set up my own firebase project I was able to get it to work. I'm receiving notifications from a firebase project someone else is in charge of. 

I was given the GoogleService-Info.plist as far as I can see everything is correct. Th Bundle_ID match & I gave them the .p8 auth key.

I still get Message ID: nil inside the didReceiveRemoteNotification method, other than that I do seem to connect up & get a Firebase token. 

Any furthere thoughts?

Comment: On a side note, I get a notification popping up. This was one I created for a background fetch but no longer use. I'm not making any calls or setting the notification up but it still pops up. Could these be related somehow & any idea why I get this notification popping up even though the code to set it up isn't called?

Answer (score 1):

Please Try With this code and debug

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


        FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)


        let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary 

        print(aps)

        print(userInfo)

        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        print("%@", userInfo)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestions, the method doesn't get called. Any idea why that might be?